# why does Spring Security store SecurityContext in thread local variable

Tags: spring, spring-security

As I know, Spring Security uses a filter to get `SecurityContext` from `HttpSession`, store it to a `ThreadLocal` variable. After the request is handled, the filter saves the `SecurityContext` back to the `HttpSession`.
My problem is why don't Spring Security just use the `SecurityContext` directly?
Why save to `Threadlocal` and save back to `HttpSession` again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring Security has a Configurable strategies to store `SecurityContext` in `SecurityContextHolder`. `ThreadLocal` variable is one strategy only. Following are the 3 strategies.

1. [ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/context/ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy.java)
2. [InheritableThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/context/InheritableThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy.java)
3. [GlobalSecurityContextHolderStrategy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/context/GlobalSecurityContextHolderStrategy.java)

In terms of `ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy`,

> My problem is way don't Spring Security just use the SecurityContext directly?

Because the way Web/Application Servers work is not same across multiple vendors (Tomcat, JBOSS). Spring Security can not be 100% certain that 1 Thread will only be used exclusively to cater one user session. A `Thread` may be shared mostly when there is a threadpool involved. So storing the `SecurityContext` in a `ThreadLocal` variable doesn't make it behave like it is in the `HttpSession`.

> Why save to Threadlocal and save back to HttpSession again?

As I explained above, the Same `Thread` could be used to process multiple requests from different users. So at the end of the request the `SecurityContext` must be vacated from the `ThreadLocal` variable so that the next request can make use it. The storing in the `HttpSession` is done to create the `SecurityContext` back when the next request from the same session comes in.

Comment: Does it mean that they could use request.getSession() instead of ThreadLocal--passing it from the controller to all the methods in the call hierarchy as a param? It would be a parameter hell, and hard to support, and hard to achieve some annotated-based authorisation magic... But would it still be a working solution?
Is it the main obstacle they've overcame using ThreadLocal, or there are others? Maybe something related to proper synchronisation?