# RabbitMQ MessageListener returns null context with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I'm working with `MessageListener` implementation receiving messages from RabbitMQ, but `securityContextHolder.getContext()` returns `null` only in `onMessage`, but it's working fine for the rest of the application:

```java
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ControleResult resultControle = gson.fromJson(new String(message.getBody()), Facture.class);
    Optional<Facture> optional = dossierDao.findById(resultControle.getId());
    Facture facture= null;
    if (optional.isPresent()) {
        facture= optional.get();
    }
  
    factureDao.save(facture);
    log.info("USER     " + getLoggedInUserName());   
}

private String getLoggedInUserName() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            ConnectedUser userDetails = (ConnectedUser) authentication.getPrincipal();

            return String.format("%s %s",userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getUserlastname());
        }
    }
    return null; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` by default uses `ThreadLocal` variable to store `Authentication` object.

When `onMessage()` function is invoked by RabbitMQ listener it will be invoked in a Thread which is new. And each new `Thread` will get its own `ThreadLocal` variable instance thus named Thread "local". This means it has no context of the current logged in user within the web application.

For more info on different Security Context Holder strategies see my answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45725888/why-does-spring-security-store-securitycontext-in-thread-local-variable) question.

Comment: I appreciate your response, Shazin. According to what I've read, using the GlobalSecurityContextHolderStrategy is not advised. Is there an alternative method for transferring the context to the thread managing the message function?